# Run a mysql query remotely from a PC without mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to automate the upload of data to a mysql database.  I am using MySql Workbench on a windows pc to remotely access my database on AWS.  I have a sql file that I use to load a csv file into the db using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.  My csv file is created daily using a scheduled task and I would like to load it into the db using a batch type file and a scheduled task.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Windows you may use PHP form [Wamp Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), its very straightforward installation. You don't need MySQL Server at your local PC to update remote AWS with the data but only a scripting language.

I would suggest to install MySQL on your local PC to check firstly on that local MySQL if the update does what you expect it to do. Once it meets your expectation you just change the MySQL connection parameters to these from AWS and your set.

In MySQL Workbench you may add additional MySQL Server as local to check the local database and all applied to it changes

Perhaps this example can help [link](https://www.codexworld.com/import-csv-file-data-into-mysql-database-php/) you to do first steps in writing php script to update database

PHP scripts can be executed form command line as well so once you write your script that updates the database you should be able to run it from windows CMD console this way

```
php -f path-to-your-sript.php
```

but if so you need to edit php scipt this way that it already knows where the csv file is and reads its content, maybe by this function [file_get_contents()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or you can also give a try a dedicated to csv files function [fgetcsv()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) that is even more suitable because it reads line by line your CSV file so if you use loop you can even process very big CSV files without running out of the memory.